# Python script to extrude with scale restriction

Tags: python, scripting, extrude

I am working on a python script and to find the right function calls I have been cutting and pasting from the top bar of the scripting window after I do the step manually. It was going great. For instance, I went into edit on an object, selected some vertices and manually did and extrude restricting it to the Z axis.  Then I put the code into my script:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"mirror":False},
                                 TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0), 
                                 "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), 
                                 "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', 
                                 "mirror":False, 
                                 "proportional":'DISABLED', 
                                 "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', 
                                 "proportional_size":1, 
                                 "snap":False, 
                                 "snap_target":'CLOSEST', 
                                 "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), 
                                 "snap_align":False, 
                                 "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), 
                                 "gpencil_strokes":False, 
                                 "texture_space":False, 
                                 "remove_on_cancel":False, 
                                 "release_confirm":False})
```

and it worked fine.

But, then I selected a different ring of vertices and did an Extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) -> Scale (<kbd>S</kbd>) then restricted the scaling to the XY plane (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) and did the scaling extrusion.  In the UI it worked fine. But, when I copy the code:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"mirror":False}, 
                                 TRANSFORM_OT_resize={"value":(2.12492, 2.12492, 2.12492), 
                                 "constraint_axis":(True, True, False), 
                                 "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', 
                                 "mirror":False, 
                                 "proportional":'DISABLED', 
                                 "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', 
                                 "proportional_size":1, 
                                 "snap":False, 
                                 "snap_target":'CLOSEST', 
                                 "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), 
                                 "snap_align":False, 
                                 "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), 
                                 "gpencil_strokes":False, 
                                 "texture_space":False, 
                                 "remove_on_cancel":False, 
                                 "release_confirm":False})
```

to the script and run it, it says:

```
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "TRANSFORM_OT_resize" unrecognized
```

Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...

I searched for `TRANSFORM_OT_resize` and I can't find any ref to it.

Comment: Just a hint: try splitting up your code so we don't have to scroll all the way to the side to see all of your code. It's easier to identify your code when all the text is on the screen at the same time.

Comment: Hi James, I'd say this is a bug, at the very least in that the reported operator call is in error.  `TRANSFORM_OT_resize` is the class name (TYPE_O*perator*T*ype*_name naming convention) of the scale operator `bpy.ops.transform.resize(...)`.  `TRANSFORM_OT_resize` is not a property of [bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_move](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_edges_move), `TRANSFORM_OT_translate` is.    Suggest reporting to the [Bug Tracker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Comment: Without testing, would say you can get around this by running extrude_move, followed by `bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(2, 2, 2), ...)`

Comment: This finally got added to the bug tracker https://developer.blender.org/T84148

Answer (score 2):

thanks batFINGER, your suggestion worked like a charm.  this is it:

```
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"mirror":False}, ...snip...
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1.5, 1.5, 1), constraint_axis=(False, False, False))
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

with some magic numbers.